# I cannot get the meta of a kdb+ table - sym error

Tags: kdb, sym

I have a table that I want to find the meta for but I keep getting the following error.
I also have similar tables with the same issue and I don't have a sym file.
The Trade table for example has the sym column present already so I'm unsure why the error outputs `'..sym`

`q)meta trade '..sym [0]  meta trade ^`

Any idea what the issue might be?

I tried updating the metadata types but I was unsuccessful resulted in more errors.

Comment: I think you for got to add the code of the different errors you have.
I would suggest you to rad the [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the error by creating a `sym` variable in memory:

```
sym:`$()
```

However the enumerated columns will be all nulls. You need the original `sym` file for the data to make sense.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/enumerations/

Comment: So is there no other way around the sym error without the sym file or over writing?